# What is the meaning of <__main__.Datos object at 0x00000259566AFE50>?

Tags: python, list

I do that in python:

```py
class Datos:
    def __init__(self):
        self.indice = int()
        self.nombre = str()
       

def GuardarMontaña(fich: str, datos: Datos)->bool:
    
    
    cad = fich.readline()
    
    while cad != "":
        if cad == '':
            ok = False
        else:
            ok = True
            
            linea1 = cad.split()
        
            datos.indice = int(linea1[0])
            datos.nombre = linea1[1]
        
            
            cad = fich.readline()
        
         
         
    return ok


def main():
    
    try:
        f = open("Pr8_C_montanas.txt", encoding = 'UTF-8')
    except:
        print("No se ha podido abrir el fichero para lectura.")
    else:
        datos = Datos()
        if(GuardarMontaña(f, datos)):
            print(datos)
        
        else:
            print("Impsible leer datos.")
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I was trying that program and I don't know why, `<__main__.Datos object at 0x00000259566AFE50>`, appears on my screen.
I have designed this program for a class exercise, in which we have a file with lines that contain the index and the name of a mountain, and we must save the data in a register where we can access it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datos class doesnt have `__str__` method, so `print(datos)` outputs `<main.Datos object at 0x00000259566AFE50>,` try:

```py
class Datos:
    def __init__(self):
        self.indice = int()
        self.nombre = str()
    def __str__(self):
        return "indice: " + str(self.indice)
```

Answer (score 1):

When an object is printed, it's converted to a string. What you're seeing here is the default implementation of `__str__` that essentially prints the location of the object in the program's memory. If you want something more meaningful, you can (and should) override it. E.g.:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.indice}: {self.nombre}'
```